# Function call on class returning object reference rather than expected value

Tags: python, class, object, python-3.7

I'm trying to write a function to return just the area code of a phone number entered as a string.

```py
class Phone(object):
    def __init__(self, phone_number):
        self.number = phone_number

    def area_code(self):
        return self.number[:3]
```

I expect the `area_code` function I've already written to access and return the first 3 digits of the number, and calling print statements on the number within the class returns the expected result. However the return from the function call itself gives `<bound method Phone.area_code of <phone_number.Phone object at 0x04034E90>>`

Comment: How are you calling the method?  It looks like you might be doing `p.area_code` instead of `p.area_code()`

Comment: Ah, That was it. I thought I had tried that but must have missed it. Thank you!